# Data inserted into the database even though it already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently coding a registration script in PHP and my problem is that the data is still inserted into the database even though it already exists. It's probably some silly mistake or I need some else{} statement or I don't really know. The thing is that even though the email already exists in the database it stills enters it.
It does display the error just fine.

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM database WHERE email='$email'");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($email_check);
    if($num_rows>0){
        echo "The email is already in use.<br>";
    }

        $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO database VALUES (NULL,'$username','$name','$email','$pwh','$date')");
  }

?>
```

If the email is already in use it displays the echo "The email is already in use." just fine, yet it still inserts it. What am I missing? I already tried using 'else' variable yet nothing helped.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question: the INSERT query is always executed here. You either need to add an else { } branch around your if block, or you need to add a return statement inside the if block.

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - that this is the wrong way to go about this to begin with. The e-mail column should get a UNIQUE index - and then you just _try_ to make the INSERT, and see what errors you get. No SELECT involved in this at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` only echo something, then you do the `INSERT` no matter what. Some solution :

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM database WHERE email='$email'");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($email_check);
    if($num_rows>0){
        echo "The email is already in use.<br>";
    }
// ADD A ELSE SO YOU INSERT IF YOU HAVE NOTHING
    else {
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO database VALUES (NULL,'$username','$name','$email','$pwh','$date')");
    }    
  }
```

Now you can prevent it from your database too :

1. Add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the column `email` from your table `database`
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` now, so it will insert if the email is not used and ignore if email is already used

And last, use prepare statement and bind param to avoind SQL injection !

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello Mickael. Thank you for trying to help me out, but as I already mentioned I already tried else{} and elseif{} sentences, yet it still inserts the data that already exists into the database.  I just tried with the code you provided me, yet it still inserts data into the database even though it already exists.

Comment: How can you insert something if your code never do the INSERT part ? If you still do the INSERT, it's because your if condition is wrong so. Try a `var_dump($num_rows)` to see what you get. And did you tried to add UNIQUE INDEX and use "INSERT IGNORE..." ?

Comment: It does the insert part. I fixed it. The bracket was at the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Your if is fine, but you then proceed to always do the insert. This is because you have put it outside the if.

what you should do is :

```
if(!$num_rows <= 0){
    <insert statement>;
}
else {
 echo "The email is already in use.<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

write this statement inside else block

```
else
{
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO database VALUES (NULL,'$username','$name','$email','$pwh','$date')");
}
```